showModal is not a function in test react testing library
I have a test for this a modal dialog component in react.
This is the modal dialog component:
export const DialogModal = ({
  showDialog,
  setShowDialog,
  options = {},
  children,
  }) => {
    const CLOSE_AFTER_ANIMATION_MS = 300;
    const OPEN_ANIMATION_DURATION = options?.openAnimationDuration || 300;
    const [showClosingAnimation, setShowClosingAnimation] =
      React.useState<boolean>(false);
    const modalRef = React.useRef<HTMLDialogElement>(null);
    options.hasBackdrop = options?.hasBackdrop ?? true;
    options.cancelable = options?.cancelable ?? true;
    options.closeAfter =
      options?.closeAfter && options?.closeAfter > 0
        ? options?.closeAfter
        : CLOSE_AFTER_ANIMATION_MS;
    const closeModalOnEsc = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDialogElement>) => 
     {
      if (e.key === 'Escape' && options.cancelable) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setShowDialog(false);
     }
    };
    const closeModalHandler = async () => {
      setShowClosingAnimation(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
          modalRef.current?.close();
          setShowClosingAnimation(false);
        }, options.closeAfter || CLOSE_AFTER_ANIMATION_MS);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
       if (showDialog) {
          options.hasBackdrop
              ? modalRef.current?.showModal()
              : setShowDialog(false);
      } else {
          closeModalHandler().then();
       }
    }, [showDialog]);

   const handleOnClick = (ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDialogElement>) => {
      if (ev.target === modalRef.current) {
          setShowDialog(false);
      }
  };

  return (
      <dialog
          // @ts-expect-error this is a valid property
          style={{ '--animation-time-var': `${OPEN_ANIMATION_DURATION}ms` 
            }}
          onClick={handleOnClick}
          onKeyDown={closeModalOnEsc}
          ref={modalRef}
          aria-hidden={!showDialog}
          role={'dialog'}
          aria-modal="true"
          aria-labelledby="dialog-title"
          className={` ${style.dialogModal} ${style.dialogBackDrop}
            ${
                showClosingAnimation
                    ? style.backdropDisappear
                    : style.backdropAppear
            }`}
            >
          <div
              className={`  ${
                  showClosingAnimation
                    ? style.dialogDisappear
                    : style.dialogAppear
             } `}
              id={'dialog-content-container'}
           >
              {children}
          </div>
      </dialog>
   );};

This is the test :
    test('component renders without errors', async ({ expect }) => {
      const setShowDialog = vi.fn();
      await act(async () => {
        render(
            <DialogModal showDialog={true} setShowDialog={setShowDialog}>
                <div>Test Text</div>
            </DialogModal>
          );
      });
      const modal = await screen.findByRole('dialog', { hidden: true });

      expect(modal).not.toBe(null);
});

I get the error:
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: modalRef.current?.showModal is not a function]
The testing stack is React (with typescript), vitest, react-testing-library.
Any idea why is this happening ?

Ok turns out there is no support yet for dialog element in JsDom. see this.
This is the proposed solution until it added:
Workaround for jest:
beforeAll(() => {
  HTMLDialogElement.prototype.show = jest.fn();
  HTMLDialogElement.prototype.showModal = jest.fn();
  HTMLDialogElement.prototype.close = jest.fn();
});

Workaround for vitest
beforeAll(() => {
  HTMLDialogElement.prototype.show = vi.fn();
  HTMLDialogElement.prototype.showModal = vi.fn();
  HTMLDialogElement.prototype.close = vi.fn();
});

